# JQuery fails to remove an element with attached event handler

Tags: jquery, events

It's probably something easy but I cannot figure it out...

I'm trying to dynamically build modal notification window, where the structure is:

```
<!-- the overlay to disable the screen interaction -->
<div id="modalWrapper"></div>

<!-- the actual window where I put the contents in dynamically -->
<div id="modalWindow"></div>
```

the structure I'm building using JQuery is:

```
<h1>Error</h1><h5>test</h5><ul class="buttons"><li class="left"><a class="button red small">Close</a></li></ul>
```

I'm attaching an event handler dynamically as well:

```
a.bind('click', function() {
    // hide wrapper and modal
    $('#modalWindow').hide();
    $('#modalWrapper').hide();
    callback();
});
```

callback function is passed as a reference to a function building the modal window.

When I call the "display" function - it builds the window and shows it but it only works ONCE. Any consecutive calls to it fail as

```
$('#modalWindow').empty();
```

fails to remove elements (namely the  nodes) with events bound to them.

I have tried:

```
$('#modalWindow').empty();
$('#modalWindow').remove();
$('#modalWindow a').each(function(index, item) { $(item).unbind('click');});
$('#modalWindow a').each(function(index, item) { $(item).remove();});
```

and all of them fail with the same error message:

```
TypeError: handleObj is undefined
()jquery-1.7.2.js (line 3057)
()jquery-1.7.2.js (line 6524)
()jquery....min.js (line 9)
()jquery-1.7.2.js (line 5906)
()xxxxxxxxxxx.js (line 392)
()xxxxxxxxxxx.js (line 282)
[Break On This Error]   

if ( ( mappedTypes || origType === handleObj.origType ) && jquery-1.7.2.js (line 3057
```

Can someone shed some light on how do I empty the #modalWindow so I can populate it again on next Notification?

I've replicated the issue using this:

```
var x = $('<a/>').html('clickme').attr('id','some_id').bind('click',function() {$(this).remove();});
$('body').append(x);
```

Please note however that the one-liner above errors out with the same message but the actual execution flow in my app is different. I'm building all the HTML and binding an event that "HIDES" the modal elements. Then on next iteration I'm trying to "empty" the modal container and "insert" new items in it and that's where it errors out - so I'm not removing the item containing the handler that is currently executing. I'm trying to remove it on next iteration.

Thanks in advance.

**ANOTHER UPDATE - just for reference though**
It seems that there might be a bug in JQuery's event dispatcher or some code around it.

```
Object.prototype.someFunctionName = function(param) {
   alert('test');
}
var x = $('<a/>').html('clickme').attr('id','some_id').bind('click',function() {$(this).remove();});
$('body').append(x);
```

causes the someFunctionName to be executed every time "click" is triggered on ANY element and mismatch of the parameters causes JQuery to choke and error out.

if we define the someFunctionName like this:

```
Object.prototype.someFunctionName = function() {
   alert('test');
}
var x = $('<a/>').html('clickme').attr('id','some_id').bind('click',function() {$(this).remove();});
$('body').append(x);
```

it works but it's still executed every time - which is wrong...
I will post that on JQuery's site - thanks guys.

works:
http://jsfiddle.net/tinnerdxp/AU4pm/

doesn't work:
http://jsfiddle.net/tinnerdxp/Pvax2/

tinnerdxp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/65M3H/ -- your sample code replicating the issue works fine here. This suggests that the problem isn't in your code, it's in some other code -- perhaps one of the plugins you appear to be using.

Comment: Let's see where you're creating the elements that you're then trying to remove, please.

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your question and setting the title to '[SOLVED]', put your solution into an *actual answer* and mark it as correct - That's the StackOverflow way.

Comment: OK I've done it for you. Please try to maintain the *question* -> *answer* flow of SO whenever possible. You should also mark your answer as correct so people will know it has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [tinnerdxp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134452/tinnerdxp)'s answer:

Thanks guys, it was my code in the end.
I have extended Object.prototype like so:

```
Object.prototype.isSet = function(property) {
    if (!(property in this)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


Object.prototype.isArray = function() {
    if (this.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array') == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the first extension was actually breaking it. Which is bit weird as:

- JQuery is not using .isSet anywhere - so I haven't overridden any of
  core functions
- Renaming isSet to something silly like amIset - still didn't fix it
- Removing isSet - fixed it although I still have .isArray() - and it works fine with that one left in.

The replication code I've put above - indeed doesn't work when I had my library (and the extension) executed - so it was wrong to post it here to begin with.

Generally speaking though:

- Thanks Blazemonger for suggestion that lead me to a resolution
- Anthony - that's a very good pointer as well - as I was originally suspecting the scope issue.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Thanks Codemonkey - I was adding another update to the answer so for future reference - the reason why it failed is explained in the "Another Update" section. Cheers guys.